# How To know how many and whom like my article?

Tags: facebook

I want  any fql or sdk function where i passed my url it give me how many and whom like this url?

Comment: What have you tried?
http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *Like event*<sup>*</sup> from the Facebook Javascript SDK, and then from there do an Ajax request, and save the details.

<sup>*Actually a callback</sup>